# floor_date not working in mutate and ifelse

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I am trying to write a generalize aggregation function where the user specifies the aggregation level or they can aggregate the data over all study dates. The `floor_date` only converts the first date. why? How can I fix this?

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

sTerm <- "year" # month, bimonth, quarter, season, halfyear and year, custom
sCustom <- "2023-2025"

dfDatasetOutput  <- data.frame(
  valDate=seq(as.Date("2023-01-01"), as.Date("2025-12-01"), by = "month"), 
  cat1=rnorm(36, 3500, 1000),
  cat2=rnorm(36, 2.5, 5)
)

dfDatasetOutput %>%
  mutate(valDate=ifelse(toupper(sTerm)=="CUSTOM", 
                          sCustom, 
                          as.character(floor_date(valDate, sTerm)))) 

# this works just fine
dfDatasetOutput %>%
  mutate(valDate=as.character(floor_date(valDate, sTerm)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem does not stem from `floor_date` but from your use of `ifelse`. As per its manual:

```
ifelse(test, yes, no)
ifelse returns a value with the same shape as test which is filled
with elements selected from either yes or no depending on whether 
the element of test is TRUE or FALSE.
```

Your test is `toupper(sTerm)=="CUSTOM"` which is a single logical element TRUE or FALSE (or NA). So the output of `ifelse` will be a single element. If the test is false, it will take this element from `as.character(floor_date(valDate, sTerm))`. It only needs one, so will take the first one. Then `mutate` recycles this single value to the length of the column.

If you want the output to be the same length as `valDate`, a workaround would be to repeat your test so you get a vector of the desired length as a test:

```
dfDatasetOutput %>%
  mutate(valDate=ifelse(rep(toupper(sTerm)=="CUSTOM",nrow(dfDatasetOutput)), 
                        sCustom, 
                        as.character(floor_date(valDate, sTerm))))
```

To avoid such unintended use of `ifelse`, consider using `if_else` which runs checks on object lengths.

Comment: No problem =) I got stumped for hours myself before I really understood how flawed and unintuitive `ifelse` is. If you consider my answer to be correct, please mark it as accepted! ;)